# INSUFFICIENT_DATA for Cloudwatch Alarm

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, cloudwatch-alarms

This is my `serverless` Cloudformation:

```
    MyAlarm1:
      Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
      Properties:
        AlarmName: "MyAlarm1"
        Namespace: AWS/SQS
        Statistic: Sum
        Period: 600
        EvaluationPeriods: 1
        Threshold: 1
        ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
        MetricName: ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
        AlarmActions:
          - arn:aws:sns:us-west2:MySNSTopic1
        Dimensions:
          - Name: QueueName
            Value: arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:MyQueueName1
```

I get the alarm successfully created via Cloudformation, however the alarm stays in `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` state. This is what I've tried so far:

1. Adding stuff to the queue which is configured as dimension in the alarm
2. Re-adjusting the evaluation periods
3. Adding subscription to the queue
4. Adding subscription to the SNS topic where the alarm publishes the event

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it. The dimensions were misconfigured. Correct configuration as follows:

```
Dimensions:
    - Name: QueueName
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - "MyQueueNameGoesHere"
          - "QueueName"
```